# Express Server Not Connecting to Mongo

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to make an express server, and connect a mongo database up to it but I'm having issues.
I installed everything with npm, and all the dependencies are in line. As far as I'm aware my server is set up correctly, but every time I try to run it, it can't connect to mongo.
I will attach my server side code and all the errors and everything.
My mongo server is running, and compass and connect to it. I've double and triple checked my connection URI and it seems in line. I just don't know what's causing the issues.

```
const express = require("express")

const mongodb = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const app = express();
const port = 3001;

const connectionStringURI = `mongodb://localhost:27017`;

let db;

mongodb.connect(
  connectionStringURI,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  (err, client) => {
    db = client.db();
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  }
)
```

Error I keep getting:

```
C:\Users\liama\work\MoonliteDrivein\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278
                const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\liama\work\MoonliteDrivein\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 312736452,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\liama\work\MoonliteDrivein\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:370:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\liama\work\MoonliteDrivein\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

[Mongo Compass setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkhl4.png)

[Mongo Server Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dK1P.png)

I've tried changing the URI, changing my mongo connection code, running the mongo server in different directories, chat gpt just takes me back to square one, same with other forums. It still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the 'localhost' part of your URI to 127.0.0.1? For clarification, try having it read:

```
const connectionStringURI = `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`;
```

Comment: I have also tried doing that, it just gives the same thing. I have no clue as to why it's not working.

Comment: @LiamAllen are you sure that this doesn't fix your problem? Your error clearly shows that there's a connection by `ipv6`, not `ipv4`. `ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017` isn't ipv4